# Willing to run a cleaning script on list of agents without the need to create seperate stage for each agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

## Problem Statement

I am willing to run a cleaning script on a list of agents contains Linux OS.
right now, the script is done and I am able to run it on a single agent at a time, or if I am willing to run it on a few agents I need to duplicate the "stage" and change the name of the agent under "label". is there a way to make it more efficient? to be able to create a list of "labels" and ask it to run them in parallel on all of the instances at the same time?

## Attempted Solutions

I tried to use `stage{agent{label "x && y"}}` and also `stage{agent{label "x || y"}}`. The first resulted with the script saying there is not label called "x&&y" and the second one just ran only the "y" label.

## Current Pipeline Code

```
pipeline 
{
  agent none
  options { timestamps () }
  stages
  {
    stage('Cleaning up label1')
      {
        agent { 
          label "label1"
          }
        steps
          {
            echo "Cleaning up unused docker images from Jenkins Instance"
            sh "date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S > datestamp.txt" 
            sh "docker system prune -a --volumes -f"
            echo "Cleaning up space from unused packages (orphaned dependencies), remove old kernels in Ubuntu"
            sh "sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge"
            echo "clean the apt cache on Ubuntu"
            sh "sudo apt-get -y clean"
          }
      }
  stage('Cleaning up label2')
      {
        agent { 
          label "label2"
          }
        steps
          {
            echo "Cleaning up unused docker images from Jenkins Instance"
            sh "date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S > datestamp.txt" 
            sh "docker system prune -a --volumes -f"
            echo "Cleaning up space from unused packages (orphaned dependencies), remove old kernels in Ubuntu"
            sh "sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge"
            echo "clean the apt cache on Ubuntu"
            sh "sudo apt-get -y clean"
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Jenkins runs your stage on a single node.

If you need to run a stage on *multiple* nodes (e.g. "all instances of the label"), you need to program it accordingly yourself.

Here's a little function we use to get all the online nodes for a given pattern (you can modify this function to look for a label instead):

```
@NonCPS
def getNodeNames(String some_pattern) {
    String[] ret_value = []
    for (Node node in Hudson.instance.nodes) {
        def nodeName = node.getNodeName()
        if (nodeName.equals(some_pattern) ||
            nodeName  ==~ '^' + some_pattern + '$') {
            if (node != null && node.toComputer() != null && node.toComputer().online) {
              ret_value += node.name 
            }
        } 
        node = null
    }
    return ret_value
}
```

Here's how you can programmatically build a pipeline to run your code on any number of nodes, known only at a runtime:

```
def builders = [:].asSynchronized()

node('master') {
    stage('Prepare the Pipeline') {
        // get deploy pattern from params or something
        def node_names = getNodeNames(deploy_pattern)
        
        for (node_name in node_names) {
            // Groovy closures stuff, need to copy it over
            def final_node_name = node_name

            builders[final_node_name] = {
                node(final_node_name) {
                    timeout(time:5, unit: "MINUTES") {
                        // have your cleanups here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have stages in `builders` variable, you can invoke them all at the same time:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'master'} }
    
    stages{
        stage ('Do the cleanup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel builders
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to simplify it a little? for example to create a list and ask it to run on the list of the labels (agents) instead of discovering it every run? and to keep the original structure?

Comment: Yes, try `def node_names = ['my_agent_1', 'my_agent_2', 'my_agent_3']` etc. Just note that you will need to edit your script every time you add, rename, or remove a node.

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick answer, my question was after ill create the list how do i make it go in parallel on all the list instead of just on one of the variables? to keep your function but change it accordingaly? "def node_names = getNodeNames(deploy_pattern)" to "def node_names = ['my_agent_1', 'my_agent_2', 'my_agent_3']" ?

Comment: You're right, that change in "Prepare the Pipeline" stage should do.